# I don't own Python 2.7.3 but somehow python --version in shell says Python 2.7.3?

Tags: python-2.7

I've searched my computer high and low and I don't have Python 2.7.3 anywhere on it, and in my PATH environment variable I have added "C:\Python34\python.exe". Yet for some reason when I run `python` in CMD it runs python version 2.7.3. I haven't a clue what could be happening, because I'm fairly certain I never installed Python 2.7.3 on this computer. What is going on?

Comment: Sorry, I realized right after I posted that you obviously are on Windows to have a C: drive.  Have you checked your full path and installed programs for Python 2.7?

Comment: Does `where.exe` exist on your system? (I think it should on Win 7).  Run `where python` from your commandline

Comment: Wow, so `where.exe` showed me that apparently it was using `C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\python\python.exe`, which I apparently installed at some point without realizing it came packed with a copy of Python 2.7.3. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, Im pretty sure you don't "own" any version of Python--the Python Software Foundation owns Python 2.7 ;-)